# VS2012 Web.config access between solutions

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

In VS2012 I have a solution with 4 projects in it.  I was curious if it was possible to access different web.config files from the other projects other than the main web.config.  I have a main project (*Project A*) and 3 other projects (B, C, D) in the same solution.  When I compile and run the program all the system.web settings are gathered from *project A* and used.  In *project A*'s web.config file is a profile tag.   Project B,C,D web.config files also contain a profile tag.  Since the solution uses *project A*'s web.config file as the default web.config then how would I access the other web.config file's profile tags?

Lets say I want to grab a profile application name from *project B*. How would I go about accessing that web.config file? When I tried to access the web.config file using:

```
ProfileManager.Providers["Profile1"].ApplicationName;
```

in `project B`'s web.config file, it gives me the application name of `Profile1`.

Well I am trying to create a profile in `ProfileBase` "ProjectB" but the system.web config says the `profileBase` default profile provider is "Profile1" from *PROJECT A*.  So the web.config file in *Project B* is not being hit and visual studio compiled the program to use web.config file from *Project A*.

```
//this is hitting profilebase from projectA, not B where I am calling the create
//(inside projectB so it uses B's web.config file or so I thought).
System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase.Create(userName);
```

**Essentially**,
I am trying to figure out how to access a profile tag from web.config file in *Project B*.  When the main web.config file is in *Project A*.  The issues arise when I try to create a profile in *Project B* using B's web.config profile attribute.  The program just creates the profile in *Project A*'s web.config profilebase which shows I am not accessing different web config files correctly.

Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated.  I am just trying to access profiles from different projects in the same solution.  So far I can only figure out how to create a profile using the main web.config file from the main project.

EX.

**In project A**

```
profile
    add name="profile1"
/profile
```

**In project B**

```
profile
    add name="profile2"
/profile
```

So in *project A* I want to be able to access *project B*'s profile and name.  This is all to run a create on *project B*'s profile base so profiles are created in A for the *project B* and stored in B.  I tried to use B's profile base by calling the create in B (which I thought would use B's web.config profile tag) but it didn't.  The program did a create for web.config of project A and stored it in A.

All four projects are said to be "Output type: class library"

Comment: What are the four project types? (web app, class library, etc)

Comment: All four projects are said to be "Output type: class library"

Comment: I was under the impression that a class library couldn't be executed on its own, so at least one of the projects needs to be something runnable, like a console app, a winforms app, etc. But assuming that to be the case, by default, a dll will use the config file of whatever application it's running in. So if Project A is the running application, the other three dlls will use Project A's config file. I think it may be possible to specify your config file, but I don't know for sure

Comment: How would I go about checking to make sure one of the projects is runnable? I looked through all of the projects and none seem to output as an app

Comment: When you created the projects, what types of projects did you create? Since you're talking about `System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase`, I assume one (probably A) is either a web site or a web application.

Comment: asp.net MVC4 web application.  I wonder why It says output type: class library then.  I created Project A first.  Project B,C,D were added to Project A later.

Comment: In the case of a web app, the web app is pretty much in control of settings and the settings should be in the web app's web.config. The class libraries should probably use the web.config, and not try to use their own config files.

Comment: I created each project as a web app so I thought it was possible to access and use web.config files of projects B,C,D?  When Project A is the main project and it's web.config file is the default web.config.

Comment: I don't think your solution is structured properly. If you have two web apps, those web apps should be completely separate applications. If you need them to communicate, it should be done via some service API like Web API or WCF, or some intermediate message system like a database. It's perfectly fine (and advisable in my opinion) to create dlls separate from the web app to store business logic, but two web apps communicating the way you've described doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Do you have reference links as to how we would do this using class libraries or web app communication methods?

Comment: Well, it depends on what you're trying to accomplish.. If you actually have two separate web applications (that will be separately hosted and have separate urls, etc), then I would look into [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456779.aspx). If you are just separating logic, you can use a class library, and add a reference to that library from your web app. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3st0d45(v=vs.100).aspx) is an msdn link on how to do that.